# ASP.Net Bootstrap Alert very long message

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a Bootstrap Alert in ASP.Net

This is my code in ASPX:

```
  <asp:Label ID="AlertLB" runat="server"/>
```

This is my code in CSS

```
  <style>
    .alert {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        height: 30px;
        line-height:30px;
        padding:0px 15px;
        display:inline-block
    }        
</style>
```

This is my Code Behind:

```
private void SetAlert(string message, string typeAlert)
{
    AlertLB.Visible = true;
    AlertLB.CssClass = "alert alert-" + typeAlert;
    AlertLB.Text = message;
    AlertLB.Focus();
}
```

This works fine when it is a short message but when it is a very long message the text goes outside the alert:

[image]

The perfect solution would be for the text to be truncated to the width of the alert:

[image]

Another solution would be for the alert height to be adjusted automatically:

[image]
Could you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Simply fix the width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching I found the following article that helped me find the solution:

https://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2013/11/aspnet-example-label-ellipsis.html

I added to my CSS code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .LabelEllipsisStyle {
        text-overflow:ellipsis;
        white-space:nowrap;
        display:block;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
```

I modified my Code Behind:

```
private void SetAlert(string message, string typeAlert)
    {
        AlertLB.Visible = true;
        AlertLB.CssClass = "alert alert-" + typeAlert + " LabelEllipsisStyle";
        AlertLB.Text = message ;
        AlertLB.Focus();
    }
```

The Solution:

[Solution Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmEQ1.png)

Answer (score 1):

According to [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow) you can add `text-truncate` class to alert label:

> For longer content, you can add a .text-truncate class to truncate the
> text with an ellipsis. Requires display: inline-block or display:
> block.

```
private void SetAlert(string message, string typeAlert)
{
    AlertLB.Visible = true;
    AlertLB.CssClass = "alert alert-" + typeAlert +" text-truncate";//added text-truncate
    AlertLB.Text = message;
    AlertLB.Focus();
}
```

Comment: I did tests with your code, but unfortunately it did not work. Thanks anyway for your attention.